# How do I initialize the Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to put Facebook posting functionality into an iOS app of mine. I'm following the Facebook tutorial, and it tells me to put this code into my AppDelegate, which I've just migrated from Objective-C:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
          
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )

        return true
    }
          
    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )

    }


}
```

There is no "ApplicationDelegate" in my code; what should I do?

Comment: Is there a problem? Does it not compile or something? `ApplicationDelegate` (called `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` in Objective-C) is a part of the Facebook SDK. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/current/FBSDKCoreKit/classes/fbsdkapplicationdelegate.html).

Comment: @Tyler: That may be the problem :) Facebook's OWN TUTORIAL didn't mention any of that! *grumble*

Comment: @Tyler: But, since you asked, YES! Even though I included the Facebook SDK as a package, Swift thinks the package doesn't exist.